# Read a txt file, and memorize into int or long in C

Tags: c, file-io, matrix

I'm not a C genius. So..first of all sorry for my stupid question.
I have a .txt file or .dta (whatever) and I want to read it in C. 
I would like to take the numbers of the txt, formatted as two columns and x rows, and memorize all the data into a matrix (or vector).

Up to know I m using this code:

```
/*
** File FILE_3.C
**
** Illustrates how to read from a file.
**
** The file is opened for reading.  Each line is successively fetched
** using fgets command.  The string is then converted to a long integer.
**
** Note that fgets returns NULL when there are no more lines in the file.
**
** In this example file ELAPSED.DTA consists of various elapsed times in
** seconds.  This may have been the result of logging the time  of events
** using an elapsed time counter which increments each second from the
** time the data logger was placed in service.
**
** Typical data in elapsed.dta might be;
**
** 653 75
** 142 90
** 104 10
** 604 10
** 124 12
**
*/

#include <stdio.h>   /* required for file operations */
FILE *fr;            /* declare the file pointer */

main()

{
   int n;
   long elapsed_seconds;
   char line[80];


   fr = fopen ("elapsed.txt", "rt");  /* open the file for reading */
   /* elapsed.dta is the name of the file */
   /* "rt" means open the file for reading text */

   while(fgets(line, 80, fr) != NULL)
   {

 sscanf (line, "%ld", &elapsed_seconds);
 /* convert the string to a long int */
 printf ("%ld\n", elapsed_seconds);
   }
   fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
} /*of main*/
```

Can you help me?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: You know, that `main()` with no `int` on the front is C programming from about 1985.  It might be time to update the example.

Comment: And what is the question? Just use sscanf http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: It's reading just the first column

Comment: So post your code, not some example what has nothing common with your problem.

Comment: How is that not working out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fscanf rather then fgets and sscanf.
And look at the scanf format carefuly (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fr;  
    int row = 0;
    int i;
    int arr[8][2]; // max 8 rows!

    fr = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    if ( fr == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Can't open file\n" );
        exit(0);
    }

    while( fscanf (fr, "%d %d\n", &arr[row][0], &arr[row][1]) == 2 )
        row ++;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        printf( "(%d) (%d)\n", arr[i][0], arr[i][1] );

    fclose(fr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate an array to hold your elapsed_second values.

```
 long * seconds_array;
 seconds_array = calloc( SIZEOFARRAY, sizeof(long));
```

In c an array is more or less the same as a pointer.

Like in this example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/

In the example pData is given a fixed size and this means that you either must know in advance how many numbers you have or you must keep track on how many numbers you've entered and allocate a new pData array when you run out of space.

In the example the numbers are taken from stdin but the principles are the same. when reading from a file. The for loop should probably be more like a while loop in your case.

```
/* calloc example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* calloc, exit, free */

int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  int * pData;
  printf ("Amount of numbers to be entered: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  pData = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));
  if (pData==NULL) exit (1);
  for (n=0;n<i;n++)
  {
    printf ("Enter number #%d: ",n+1);
    scanf ("%d",&pData[n]);
  }
  printf ("You have entered: ");
  for (n=0;n<i;n++) printf ("%d ",pData[n]);
  free (pData);
  return 0;
}
```

PS dont forget to call free on your array when you are done with it.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/